# Launch browsable intent in correct app

Tags: java, android

my problem is the following:

My app has an activity that has this declared in the manifest:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

i am using this to launch my app when i click on a link received by sms. The problem is that the app starts running in the messages context and when i press the back button it launches the app in the default context.
What i want is, when i click the link, it opens the app in its own context.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working by using this on the manifest:

```
 android:launchMode="singleTask"
```